# Cannot run an app due to ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java

I am trying to run an application on my mac and I got this error:

```java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

the full message is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.seagrid.desktop.SEAGridDesktop at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at fxlauncher.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:163) at fxlauncher.Launcher.lambda$start$3(Launcher.java:65) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that the lib containing the SEAGridDesktop class, is not in the classpath. just add the missing jars to your classpath.